When is it appropriate to include random intercepts in repeated measures mixed model?
I have a question on when it is appropriate to use random intercepts. I have a repeated measures experiment with 4 treatments. Each treatment is present once in rows in a greenhouse (blocks = rep). Data is collected from 10 plants in a PLOT (different #s) for 13 weeks. I get very different results if I give blocks a random intercept.

I get very different results if I give blocks a random intercept:
PROC GLIMMIX DATA=AVG initglm pconv=1e-4 plots=residualpanel; 
CLASS PLOT REP TRT WK;
MODEL XWF = TRT|WK / dist=negbin link=log ddfm=kr2/*use this for repeated measures*/;
random intercept/subject=REP;
random REP / subject=PLOT;
random  WK / type=ar(1) subject=PLOT residual;
LSMEANS TRT|WK/ lines slicediff=WK ilink adjust=Tukey plots=meanplot (cl join);
RUN;


PROC GLIMMIX DATA=AVG initglm pconv=1e-4 plots=residualpanel; 
CLASS PLOT REP TRT WK;
MODEL XWF = TRT|WK / dist=negbin link=log ddfm=kr2/*use this for repeated measures*/;
random REP / subject=PLOT;
random  WK / type=ar(1) subject=PLOT residual;
LSMEANS TRT|WK/ lines slicediff=WK ilink adjust=Tukey plots=meanplot (cl join);
RUN;


